# Site.com pagination < 1 2 3 4 ... >

Tags: site.com, pagination

How to implement pagination on site.com page like:

```
< 1 2 3 4 ... > or < 1 Page of 8 >
```

I was able to add '<' / '>' pagination controls with action events based on data repeater but  I am curious how to calculate page count from data repeater and render paging digits.